# angularjs binding/scope issue for select list?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

OK switching my code to angularjs and the angular 'way', not sure what I am doing wrong.

A select list is not getting updated when the model changes unless I call $apply, and I find myself calling apply a lot.

index.html has this:

```
<div id='rightcol' data-ng-include="'partials/rightSidebar.html'"  
    data-ng-controller="rightSidebarController">
</div>
```

and rightSidebar.html has this:

```
<select id='srcList' size='10'
        data-ng-model="data.source" 
        data-ng-click='srcOnclick()'
        data-ng-options="s.title for s in data.srcList | filter:{title:data.srcFilter} | orderBy:'title'"></select>
```

rightSidebarController.js has this:

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.srcList = dataProvider.getSourceList();
$scope.data.source = dataProvider.getSource();
```

dataProvider is a service that makes an asynchronous database call (IndexedDB) to populate srcList, which is what gets returned in dataProvider.getSource().

Is it the asynchronous database call that forces me to call $apply, or should the controller be ignorant of that?

Is there a 'better' way to do this?

Edited to add service code.

Another controller calls dataProvider.refreshSourceList:

```
myDB.refreshSourceList = function() {
    myDB.getRecords("source", function(recs) {
        myDB.srcList = recs;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('SrcListRefresh');
    });
};
```

myDB.srcList is the field being bound by $scope.data.srcList = dataProvider.getSourceList();

myDB.getRecords:

```
myDB.getRecords = function(storeName, callback) {
    var db = myDB.db;
    var recList = [];
    var trans = db.transaction([storeName], 'readonly');
    var store = trans.objectStore(storeName);

    var cursorRequest = store.openCursor();
    cursorRequest.onerror = myDB.onerror;

    cursorRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
        var cursor = cursorRequest.result || e.result;
        if (cursor === false || cursor === undefined) {
            if (callback !== undefined) {
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    callback(recList);
                });
            }
        } else if (cursor.value !== null) {
            recList.push(cursor.value);
            cursor.continue();
        }
    };

    cursorRequest.onerror = myDB.onerror;
};
```

Comment: Show where the model is changing and its not updating the view

Comment: You have to call $apply if you are not using $resource or $http -- i.e., if you are doing something "outside" of Angular you need to call $apply so that Angular will run a digest cycle and check all of the $watches that have been set up.

Comment: Mark, my originally implementation generates an event when the field changes, and interested parties are calling the $apply.  I instinctively sense that is not the angular way though, and I get $apply already in progress msgs frequently.

Comment: James I updated the code as requested

Comment: The issue has been resolved - I misunderstoond pass by reference meant pass a copy of a reference.  I have re designed my app accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you do async needs to be wrapped in `$scope.$apply()`. This is because angular works in a similar fashion to a game loop, however instead of constantly running, it knows to end the loop when an action is taken, and `$scope.$digest()` is called.

If you are using IndexedDB, I would recommend creating an angular wrapper for it, like so:
(forgive my IndexedDB code, I'm not experience with it)

```
angular.module('app',[])
    .factory('appdb', function($rootScope){
        var db = indexedDB.open('appdb', 3);
        return {
            get : function(table, query, callback) {
                var req = db.transaction([table])
                    .objectStore(table)
                    .get(query);

                req.onsuccess(function(){
                    $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                        callback(req.result);
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

This way you can be sure that any data retrieve and set on a controller scope inside of `callback` will have `$scope.$digest()` called afterward.

Comment: I see no change in behavior when I 1) wrap the callback in an $apply or 2) implement a promise that is resolved onsuccess.

Comment: INtersting, if I link direct to srcList instead of calling getSourceList(), it works - sort of - still have to reset the variable in an $on call